# Plotting multiple charts with a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm having an issue while trying to plot multiple charts with a `for` loop in python.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(Opts_Data_All),figsize=(20,10))

for index, contract in enumerate(Opts_Data_All):
    
    ax[index].set_xlabel('Strike')
    ax[index].set_ylabel('Imp Vol')
    ax[index].set_title(key)
    ax[index].plot(Opts_Data_All[contract]['IV']) 
    
plt.show()
```

The code above will only squeeze the plots in one figure but I would like to have the charts as subplot.
Total there are 17 plots as there are 17 keys for the dictionary `Opts_Data_All`.

Image attached is the result I get

[image]

Comment: They are subplots. Do you mean that you want them all in a single plot?

Comment: it felt like they werent. I thought one subplot will be in the figure object. But all subplots are in one figure here. The goal will be to have one fig per plot

Comment: So you want each plot to be in a separate figure?

Comment: I think that will be better yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each plot to be in its own figure, then you need to create a new figure in each iteration of the loop.

```py
for contract in Opts_Data_All:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
    ax.plot(Opts_Data_All[contract]['IV']) 
    ax.set_xlabel('Strike')
    ax.set_ylabel('Imp Vol')
    ax.set_title(key)
    fig.show()
```